# Get Image upon page init

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to get my image from my firebase storage when I enter the user-profile.

I've tried something for myself but that doesn't work.

upload.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireStorage } from '@angular/fire/storage';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { User, NgAuthService } from '../auth/auth.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class UploadService {
  file: File;
  url = '';
  constructor(private afStorage: AngularFireStorage, @Inject(NgAuthService) private user: User) { }
  iUser = this.user.uid;
  basePath = `/uploads/images/${this.iUser}`;

  //method to upload file at firebase storage
  async uploadFile(event: any) {
    this.file = event.files[0]
    const filePath = `${this.basePath}/${this.file.name}`;    //path at which image will be stored in the firebase storage
    const snap = await this.afStorage.upload(filePath, this.file);
    if (this.file) {
      this.getUrl(snap);
    } else {
      console.log("Select a image please.")
    }
    this.getUrl(snap);
  }

  //method to retrieve download url
  async getUrl(snap: firebase.storage.UploadTaskSnapshot) {
    await snap.ref.getDownloadURL().then(url => {
      this.url = url;  //store the URL
      console.log(this.url);
    });
  }
}
```

user-profile.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UploadService } from '../../storage/upload.service';
import { AngularFireStorage } from '@angular/fire/storage';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-profile',
  templateUrl: './user-profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-profile.component.scss'],
})
export class UserProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    public uploadService: UploadService,
    public afStorage: AngularFireStorage,
    ) { }

    image = this.uploadService.url;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.uploadService.getUrl();
  }
}
```

No idea how I'm supposed to do it. I wanted to do it with the private method from my service file but it wants me to provide a parameter that I don't have in my component file. I then tried to just call I can try and provide a StackBlitz for this.

Link to StakBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-34jf1q?

Comment: Your problem is that you try to call the `getUrl` function that receives the `snap` argument, yet when you call it in your component you lack that argument in the call.

Comment: @mutantkeyboard That is the problem. I want to use the function, but I can't get the snap argument from anywhere besides writing in a value for it above. Afaik. I'm no expert in that part at all.

Comment: The flow you are trying to do is to call the service you created in the component and get a value. only the method you trigger in ngOnInit does not return a value, so you cannot reflect the url value in html. The service you have created for such transactions is to update it to return a value. However, you have designed your structure in such a way that you cannot access the url variable without uploading a file. For this reason, you should separate the `uploadFile` and` getURL` methods from each other.

Comment: @OnurÖzkır Do you have any suggestions as to how I should separate them from each other? I have a few ideas, but wanted to get some input on that part.

Comment: Thinking of an idea I was thinking I could "reuse" the `const snap` down inside the `getUrl` function? And then just remove the snap parameter and hope it works? I mean I will give it a test when I'm in front of my code tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

One great way to get asynchronous data on page load is to use [Resolvers](https://codeburst.io/understanding-resolvers-in-angular-736e9db71267), which allow you to call api calls and retrieve data before the route navigation completes so that when you arrive all your data is there.

Unfortunately, I'm not familiar enough with firebase to know about getting the 'snap' argument. It may be worth looking into [AngularFire](https://github.com/angular/angularfire) to make things simpler (maybe?)
Best of luck!

Comment: I'm using AngularFire, but only using the part of it that is required for Firebase Storage. `import { AngularFireStorage } from '@angular/fire/storage';` this is the line I'm talking about in this sense.

Comment: I will try and give it a try. Seems like I can use it if I don't get another way of separating the functions.

Comment: Idk if resolvers will answer everything, but it is a clean way to load things when navigating to new routes.
There must be something in firebase/angular fire for loading data explicitly, or so I'd hope

Comment: I have fixed it. Though without the use of resolvers. I decided to separate the functions. I just made the `const filePath` again down inside my `getUrl` function. And also made `snap` a const. And I also did some other work, which has helped a lot more to solving the issue.